# Caching an XDocument object. Is it worth it?

Tags: asp.net, xml, caching

I am loading an XML file in my local server (not a remote server) using:

```
XDocument.Load(path_to_xml_file);
```

This file is 500KB. I am wondering if I should cache the XDocument instead of reading the file every time. Thank you for the guidance.

Comment: How often do you read the file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how often you are going to need it. Consider that apart from the loading time there is also a parsing time which occurs every time you load it from disk.
If your file is not willing to change very often you can put your XDocument in the cache, and defining a file dependency on the file itself, so that the cache is invalidated everytime your document changes. There is an example for this in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx)